# powershell run from cmd to to start program and exit. The program will stay running, but powershell should extit

Tags: powershell, cmd, exit, execution

I am trying to run windowed version on JlinkGDBServer (it is the windows application with GUI) at the end of the Ninja build process.

The powershell is run from the `cmd`

```
cmd.exe /C "powershell  & "C:/Program Files (x86)/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer.exe" -port 2331 -s -CPU Cortex-M -device STM32L476RG -endian little -speed 4000 -vd &"
```

but the powershell does not exit (the jlinkGDBserver window should remain)

---

Edit: It is run from the Ninja script generated by the Cmake. I have only partial control here.

## The solution:

```
powershell -command Start-Process -FilePath "'C:/Program Files (x86)/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer.exe'" -ArgumentList '-port 2331', '-s', '-CPU Cortex-M', '-device stm32l476RG', '-endian little', '-speed 4000', '-vd'
```

Comment: @KenWhite If it was so easy I would not ask this question. I am calling it from the Ninja build script generated by the CMake.

Comment: Then you should have included that in your original question. We can't read your mind, so all the information available needs to be in your post.

Comment: Have you tried `Start-Process`? Is there any reason that PowerShell must be used to start the program?

Comment: @lit there is no any reason. I just try to start the program. I will try Start-proces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can call `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe`, you should also be able to call the program directly. I don't know why you're invoking `cmd.exe` to invoke `powershell.exe` to invoke `JLinkGDBServer.exe`.

Unless there's some nuance with ninja I don't understand this should be all you need to run your command:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer.exe" -port 2331 -s -CPU Cortex-M -device STM32L476RG -endian little -speed 4000 -vd
```

---

For the record, your PowerShell process likely isn't exiting for one of two reasons:

1. You didn't use call it with `powershell.exe -command`. This works similarly to `cmd.exe /c`, where it runs the command and exits. Omitting this parameter will run whatever you tell it and then drop back to interactive mode (unless you execute it as a non-interactive user).
2. It's also possible that `JLinkGDBServer.exe` blocks execution and wasn't even dropping back to interactive mode once the process launched. In this case you can wrap the command with `Start-Job` which will start it without attaching it to your current PowerShell process. For example:

   ```
   powershell -command "Start-Job { 'C:/Program Files (x86)/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServer.exe' -port 2331 -s -CPU Cortex-M -device STM32L476RG -endian little -speed 4000 -vd" }
   ```

   Using `Start-Job` is fundamentally similar to appending an `&` to the end of your command in Linux, and should give you the same effect here.

Comment: `If you can call cmd.exe or powershell.exe` cmd is called automatically by the Ninja script. I used `-command` and it did not help. Powershell waits for the program to terminate. In Linux it is easy.

Comment: I don't understand why you're calling `JLinkGDBServer.exe` from PowerShell if ninja runs programs through `cmd`. Just run `JLinkGDBServer.exe` directly from ninja, remove PowerShell entirely from the equation.

Comment: I updated with a new code sample showing how to use `Start-Job` with your command.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, if the OP just wants the job started and is not going to do further monitoring, is there any advantage to using `Start-Job` rather than `Start-Process`?

Comment: Either will work in this case, since OP doesn't care about interacting with the process any further after launching it. I opted to suggest `Start-Job` since OP seems concerned with "ease", and it requires less named arguments.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest eventually I have forced it to work. Thank you. I have amended the answer to show the solution